# CSS styling missing after SSL certificate installation

Tags: css, ssl

Working on a website for a friend of mine and he wanted to instal ssl. someone told him it helps with seo so i did it for him. Only problem is that when you go to the website using https://prescottazhomesearch.com the styling isnt working properly.
I looked in the source on my browser and can see it calling for stylesheets that have absolute urls "http://"stylesheet".css" and not relative ones so i think that might be the problem but im not sure. Now I did not do the initial build for him so I am having a tough time trying to find out what file is calling these other stylesheets so i can change the urls.
Any insight is super appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Tell me if my answer resolves Your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all `http://` to `https://`.

Dont use `//` if Your website supports old ie versions.

Few logs from my Chrome console:

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/layerslider.custom.css?ver=5.1.1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/thickbox.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/tubepress.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/subscriptions.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
2www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/client.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/default.css?v=1407352779&ver=2.1.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/layerslider.css?ver=5.1.1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/mappress.css?ver=2.42.1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/polls-css.css?ver=2.63'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/widgets.css?ver=20121003'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/autocomplete.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/aep.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/wp-listings.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/wp-listings-widgets.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/bizdir.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/schooldir.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/srp.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/download-css.css?ver=1.50'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/style.css?ver=1.4.6'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Front-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Front-of-Home-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/front-of-home-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Front-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/P1030184_85_86_87_88_89_90-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Front-of-Home-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/U.S.A-Prescott1Arizona1-150x150.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/victorianestatesPic2-150x150.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Eastman-website-2-150x150.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:46 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:47 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/thickbox.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:48 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/tubepress.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:49 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/subscriptions.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:50 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/client.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:51 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/client.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:52 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/default.css?v=1407352779&ver=2.1.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:53 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/layerslider.css?ver=5.1.1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:54 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/mappress.css?ver=2.42.1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:55 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/polls-css.css?ver=2.63'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:56 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/widgets.css?ver=20121003'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:58 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/autocomplete.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:59 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/aep.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:60 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/wp-listings.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:61 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/wp-listings-widgets.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:62 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/bizdir.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:63 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/schooldir.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:64 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/srp.css?ver=3.9.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:65 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/download-css.css?ver=1.50'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:66 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/css/style.css?ver=1.4.6'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:434 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Front-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:434 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Front-of-Home-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:434 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/front-of-home-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:434 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Front-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:434 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/P1030184_85_86_87_88_89_90-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:434 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Front-of-Home-560x380.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:706 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/U.S.A-Prescott1Arizona1-150x150.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:708 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/victorianestatesPic2-150x150.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:710 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Eastman-website-2-150x150.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
jquery.cycle2.js:821 [cycle2] --c2 init--
jquery.cycle2.js:821 [cycle2] autoHeight: container (string)
jquery.cycle2.js:821 [cycle2] slides: > div.testimonial_slide (string)
jquery.cycle2.js:821 [cycle2] timeout: 2000 (number)
jquery.cycle2.js:821 [cycle2] fx: fade (string)
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/U.S.A-Prescott1Arizona1.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/thumbbutte.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/prescott-home1.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/kitchen.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/prescottluxury1.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
www.prescottazhomesearch.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/U.S.A-Prescott1Arizona1.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: so where there are these:<link rel='stylesheet' id='dsidxpress-unconditional-css'  href='http://www.prescottazhomesearch.com/wp-content/plugins/dsidxpress/css/client.css?ver=4.1.1' type='text/css' media='all' /> I need to replace the http:// to https://?

Comment: so where there are these:

Comment: I just cant seem to track down the file that has those links.

Comment: My proposition is create new question, about how to change this on Wordpress, if You dont know where exactly u must change it. Here is Your default, current used theme path: `wp-content/themes/curb-appeal-evolved/`.